# mongodb to store request and response for various SOAP webservices

Tags: java, mongodb, soap

I am very new to MongoDB and trying to get little more understanding before I implement this.
I am a Junior Developer. The whole application that I am working on is built on web services.
We are trying to store request and responses for all calls in MongoDB.
For example I am trying to store request against account number(User account) in the database to get a report of what happened on that account ten days ago. We would want to use MongoDB for this approach.
We have lot of requests coming for the same account, I am afraid it might take lot of memory.

Please let me know what will be the best possible approach and excuse me if I didn't explain clearly above, please let me know so I can certainly explain in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should detail more the data retrieval scenario to know if document base store is the good one.  From which bite of data you should be able to retrieve the data.  MongoDB is not a memory data store, so if you are using 64 bits the disk space will be the limit.  The storage size shouldn't be related to the nuber of request but to the number of possible response and size of the response.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I have one more question, if we already have logged data I can store logged data in mongodb using mongodb java. But is there anyways I can point this java code to a datasource and deploy it in weblogic server?  Thanks in advance..